# Error with local variable

Tags: c#, variables, scope

The following function is generating an error, "Use of unassigned local variable 'intLast'.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
    static string RemovePath(string strInput)
    {

        int intLast;

        for (int i = 1; i < strInput.Length; i++)
        {
            if (strInput.Substring(i, 1) == @"\")
            {
                intLast = i;
            }
        }

        string strOutput = strInput.Substring(strInput.Length - intLast);

        return strOutput;
    }
```

Comment: Won't that remove just the first path part making the loop redundant? FYI there are utility functions such as `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()`

Comment: System.IO.Path.GetFileName() is much easier!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the variable `intLast` at the following line:

```
string strOutput = strInput.Substring(strInput.Length - intLast);
```

But the variable will have a value only under certain conditions (`strInput.Length > 1` and `strInput.Substring(i, 1) == @"\"`). therefor the error.

To solve this provide a default value on the declaration:

`int intLast = 0; // or any default value.`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `intLast` with some value as loop can not ensure that value is assigned as the execution of loop is decided on runtime.

```
 int intLast = 0;
```

The following lines is asking for unassigned variable as control might not go into loop to assign value.

```
string strOutput = strInput.Substring(strInput.Length - intLast);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you assign `intLast` only inside of a conditional, from the compiler's perspective it is possible for you to use it without initializing it.

You should initialize it to some default value at the start even if you do not expect to ever use that.

```
int intLast = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a default value to `intLast`.

Try this:

```
static string RemovePath(string strInput)
{
    int intLast = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < strInput.Length; i++)
    {
        if (strInput.Substring(i, 1) == @"\")
        {
            intLast = i;
        }
    }

    string strOutput = strInput.Substring(strInput.Length - intLast);

    return strOutput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Edit**:

```
int intLast = 0;
```

**Whole Code will look like this:**

static string RemovePath(string strInput)
    {
        int intLast = 0;

```
    for (int i = 1; i < strInput.Length; i++)
    {
        if (strInput.Substring(i, 1) == @"\")
        {
            intLast = i;
        }
    }

    string strOutput = strInput.Substring(strInput.Length - intLast);

    return strOutput;
}
```

You just have to assign `intLast` to zero initially.

Answer (score 0):

You should *initialized* your `intLast` variable.

The compiler doesn't know that variable like `intLast` will be assigned no matter what.

```
 int intLast = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialized your variable like

```
int intLast = 0;
```

Because it might remain unassigned if it code not reach in if condition.